# SORT DATA ON THE EARLIEST AMONG SET OF SAME PARTS WITH DIFFERENT TIMES

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have a table with the following data

```
PART    MACHINE DATE
ABCPART MACHINEA    2020-03-30 13:55:41.633
DEFPART MACHINEA    2020-03-30 12:55:41.633
DEFPART MACHINEA    2020-03-30 11:55:41.633
DEFPART MACHINEA    2020-03-30 10:55:41.633
GHIPART MACHINEA    2020-03-30 09:55:41.633
ABCPART MACHINEA    2020-03-30 08:55:41.633
ABCPART MACHINEA    2020-03-30 07:55:41.633
ABCPART MACHINEA    2020-03-30 06:55:41.633
DEFPART MACHINEA    2020-03-30 05:55:41.633
DEFPART MACHINEA    2020-03-30 04:55:41.633
DEFPART MACHINEA    2020-03-30 03:55:41.633
```

I would like to extract the below data from the above result set using rank function but its not possible.

the desired output I would like to see is

```
 Part       Machine     Date
 ABCPART    MACHINEA    2020-03-30 13:55:41.633
 DEFPART    MACHINEA    2020-03-30 12:55:41.633
 GHIPART    MACHINEA    2020-03-30 09:55:41.633
 ABCPART    MACHINEA    2020-03-30 08:55:41.633
 DEFPART    MACHINEA    2020-03-30 05:55:41.633
```

i tried the below but didn't work

```
SELECT PART, MACHINE, DATE,  
DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY [PART], MACHINE ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS RN
FROM @TEMP
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '3/13/2020' AND '3/18/2020' 
ORDER BY MACHINE, DATE DESC
```

Comment: Why DESC in `ORDER BY DATE DESC`? Don't you want the earliest date?

Comment: please see the above-desired output. the part numbers are repeated below but I need the earliest among the set.